# Sort Range in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to sort a range in Google Spreadsheet with Apps Script.

The range contains two columns, the first one contains data, the second one a description of the data.

When sorting the data column alphabetical, I want the description column to sort in the same order. How could I do that?

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you try `sort()`?

Comment: You forgot to mention what is wrong with your current script/code you have made yourself to solve you **own** problem. Please refer to [ask] a question with an [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. Note that *"How could I do that?"* is off-topic for SO which is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Yes I tried. It is only sorting the data column, but not the description column.

Comment: Can you post the code here please? Because In my case it is doing exactly what you want.

Comment: I found my mistake. My range did not include the description column. For anybody reading this:
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, material.getRange('A2').getDataRegion().getLastRow(), 2).sort(1);
works fine

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to @JvdV's comment before asking any questions.
About your problem, I believe this is what you wanted.

**Code :**

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet7').getRange('A1:B6').getValues();
  console.log("Before Sort : ",data);
  console.log('------ using data.sort() ---------');
  console.log("After Sort : ",data.sort());
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

I'm really sorry if I misunderstood your question and I would require some more details.